# How to make breadcumbs grab taxonomy terms and use tokens

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, breadcrumbs

I have tried about 4 different breadcrumb modules now and none of them seem to do what I want. I want them to act in a similar way to Pathauto whereby I can mix and match tokens. There seems not to be a way to do this, for some reason or another. Example, I have a school that belongs to a country name and city name. City and country are part of a taxonomy, so:

```
/united-states/los-angeles/school-name
```

I want this to be:

```
Home > Destinations > Parent Term > Child term > Node title
```

I even might want to add my own text for one of these breadcrumbs.

Comment: what version of drupal you are using?

Comment: Drupal 7, sorry, should have said.

Comment: Is there a special reason you need tokens for this? I would propose [Crumbs](https://drupal.org/project/crumbs), which likely does what you need. It does support tokens for "Entity parent" settings on admin/structure/crumbs/entity-parent, but likely you can achieve the same in a cleaner way without tokens.

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you have not tried [Taxonomy Breadcrumb](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_breadcrumb) module yet, give it a try.

If you already have tried that module and had no success , you can write your own code.

the simplest solution can be achieved by implementing hook_preprocess_page, then you should check if there is a node and node is of a certain type used to store school type and then you can change `$variables['breadcrumb']` to modify breadcrumb as you wish.

in drupal 7 you also can use [drupal_set_breadcrumb](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_set_breadcrumb/7.x) to change breadcrumb in a code and in drupal 8 you can implement [hook_system_breadcrumb_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_system_breadcrumb_alter/8.2.x) to make it done.

Comment: I have not tired the Taxonomy Breadcrumb one as it says this: "This project is not covered by the security advisory policy.
Use at your own risk! It may have publicly disclosed vulnerabilities." If it's better to do this with code, then I'll have to pay a developer to help. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Or try [Custom Breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs). If you do hire someone maybe the easiest would be to have them address the security issues in those modules, because these modules already offer features you need, and you might encounter similar security issues with any solution you try.